# Call a class from another class - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched around the SOF and couldn't find a simple answer for my simple question.

I have two classes, `Author` and `Book`.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

    def greet
        puts "Hello, I'm #{name}."
    end

    def describe
        puts "That Author's name is #{name}.
        puts "This author wrote this book #{book}." #<--- I want to write this or combine it with the line above
    end

end
```

In class book, I don't have anything just

`class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

How can I `puts` the following:
`That Author's name is ... and This author wrote this ...` when I enter `Author.first.describe` in the Rails console?

Comment: firstly few syntax error in the code, also what are you trying to achieve here.. im not getting.

Comment: as stated above, its not quite clear what your goal is, do you have any relations defined that connect Author and Book? What is your expected output from the `#{book}` segment in your string? What have you attempted so far? More information and clarity would go a long way to helping us provide an answer for you

Comment: @JohnHayes-Reed Each author has a 1 book and it's assigned to him in his table with a `book_id` which matches the `book_id` in the `books` table.

Comment: I have written an answer based on the information you just commented, hope it can help you or get you on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the information you gave me in the comment your relations would look something like this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :author
end
```

The describe method in your Author class could look something like

```
def describe
  "That Author's name is #{name}. This author wrote this book #{book.title}."
end
```

This is based on you stating you have the book_id in your authors table, and I am also assuming you have a title or name field in your books table.

However, it feels more natural to have the Author owning the book, and the book belonging to the Author, so might I suggest changing your data structure a bit to remove the book_id from authors table, and instead place an author_id in book table, and then your models relations would look like this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I messed up the relationships, and it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :author
```

and in the migration author:references

```
 class CreateServices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.text :require
      t.integer :price
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

this is a project i'm working on, i'm using user but in your case is author.

Comment: Thank you, I actually have the tables set up. I just need to output the author's name and the books when I enter for example: `Author.first.describe` in the console

Comment: Thank you, I think I messed up the relationships, and it's working now!